# SonarQube-6.7.3 How can we aggregate project data

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube-6.7.3. We have several teams (6) who share the one production instance.

I'm looking for a way to aggregate artefact data in a custom way.   For each project we would like to aggregate artefact data so that each project manager can follow the code quality of its project?

Thanks all.

Comment: Something like [portfolio management](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+Portfolios+and+Applications)? Your question is rather vague.

Comment: I will venture to be more precise.   We have data for each artefact.    That is way too detailed for our managers.    They would like to aggregate the data to be able to follow the same metrics for a projet comprised of several artefacts.